# Pagination not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have pagination on my view which is working fine if i am clicking on next number link.like:

```
1 2 >
```

So if i am clicking on 2 it goes on second page and shows proper result.but now if i want to come back on 1 than its not redirecting me. Even if there is link 3 than i couldn't come on 2.

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
function list_providers()
{

    $admin_session_data= $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');

    $this->load->model('/admin/provider_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/admin/provider/list_providers/";
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->provider_model->countprovider();
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config['creat_link'] = 1;
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $offset=($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $data['list']= $this->provider_model->listproviders($config['per_page'],$offset);

    //$data['customer']= $this->provider_model->getcustomer_data($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));


    if(!empty($data))
    {   
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_header',$admin_session_data); 
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_top_nav',$admin_session_data); 
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_left',$admin_session_data);
        $this->load->view('admin/provider_list',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_footer',$admin_session_data);
    }

}
```

Model:

```
function listproviders($num,$offset)
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //$query=$this->db->get_where('users', array('user_role_id'=>'3'));
    $query=$this->db->get('users',$num,$offset);

    // return result set as an associative array
    return $query->result_array();
}


function countprovider()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $query=$this->db->count_all_results('users');
    return $query;
}
```

And my pagination is showing like this: 1 2 >

Please see where is problem.

Comment: `$config['creat_link'] = 1;` check this

Comment: i think there is a bug in the pagination library because i had the same problem using it couple of days ago

Comment: @raheelshan But it is working perfectly for me

Comment: @BhuvanRikka ,can u plz mis match from this code to your code,even i am not getting  First && Last option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some changes to your controller and model. Changes are commented:

**Controller**

```
// admin/provider/list_providers/3 <- Offset number
function list_providers($offset = null)
{    
    $admin_session_data= $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');

    // Load models/libraries/helpers
    $this->load->model('admin/provider_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    // Pagination config
    $config['base_url'] = site_url('index.php/admin/provider/list_providers') . '/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->provider_model->countprovider();
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    // $config['creat_link'] = 1; <-- This is not a valid option
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';

    // Init config
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    // If the pagination library doesn't recognize the current page add:
    $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;

    $data['list']= $this->provider_model->listproviders($config['per_page'],$offset);

    if(!empty($data))
    {   
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_header',$admin_session_data); 
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_top_nav',$admin_session_data); 
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_left',$admin_session_data);
        $this->load->view('admin/provider_list',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin_footer',$admin_session_data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function listproviders($num,$offset)
{
    // $this->load->library('pagination'); <-- There is no need for this
    $query = $this->db->get('users', $num, $offset);

    // Check if pages where found
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}


function countprovider()
{
    // $this->load->library('pagination'); <-- There is no need for this
    return $this->db->count_all_results('users');
}
```

Comment: yeah...all changes is acceptable but its not resolved my issue.

Comment: Could you try to add ( see controller ):
    `$this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;`

Comment: awesome this works...!!if i add $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;
what is this issue philo?

Comment: The CodeIgniter pagination library tries to get the current page based on the base_url. In some projects I've had the same issue where CodeIgniter was unable to determine the current page. So when you use `$this->pagination->cur_page` you overwrite it with the correct value :)

Comment: ok thanks ..but my all parmeters like  $config['first_link'] = 'First'; doesnt working and i want the fancy look to my pagination.could you plz help me.

Comment: Did you remove `$this->load->library('pagination');` from your model?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16730/discussion-between-philo-and-harshal-mahajan)

Answer (score 1):

Create links directly from library..
Like this..

```
$data['links']= $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And in view give something like

```
<div align="center" style="margin-top:10px;background-color: #F1F8E0">
       <?php echo $links; ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Sample code:

```
function  __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('array');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->model('listing','',TRUE);
    }

    // Shows pagination

    function index($uri_segment="3")
{   
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/listing_controller/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->listing->get_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $output['op']=$this->listing->get_paging_data($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
        $output['links']= $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('listing_view',$output);
    }
```

And the snippet in view file is shown above

Comment: @HarshalMahajan did you pass the uri->segment as argument to function index?

Comment: insted of passing directly i took this in a varible name $offset,it gives value fine.and i think there is no big diffrence in your and my code.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Not a problem.. Be sure you pass the `uri->segment` as argument to `index()`

Comment: @HarshalMahajan Working now? If not ,what error are you getting?

Comment: @bhuvan..its still giving same issue as i told in question.unable to come on previous page.